# How to set ansible_async_dir in ansbile 2.5?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

The default async directory is '~/.ansible_async' in ansible 2.5. I want to change the directory by setting ansible_async_dir like this:

```
- name: this is an async task
  shell: date
  async: 30
  poll: 0
  vars:
    ansible_async_dir: '/data/.ansible_async'
```

But which doesn' work and the results_file of async task is still under ~/.ansible_async. Any advice? 
Ansible version: 2.5.0b1

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to define this variable on the `play` level, not the `task`.

Example:

```
---
- name: play name
  hosts: pi_group
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    ansible_async_dir: '/tmp/ansible_async'


  tasks:
  - name: run async task
    shell: "date; sleep 100"
    async: 30
    poll: 0
```

Then, the async directory will be created on each affected host.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But which still doesn't work.

Comment: i am using ansible 2.8.4, not sure if there is a fix/change about this particular issue inbetween our versions. you could browse the issues/bugs of ansible on github, or the release notes and hopefully you could find something about it, or just upgrade to the latest ansible :)